# Proving an object is a tensor by contraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus

I have seen the claim that if $V_{\mu}$ is a covector, and $T^{\mu\nu}V_{\nu}$ is a vector, then $T^{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor. I am trying to prove this, and I have two questions.

It seems to rest upon the statement that $$(T^{\mu\nu}V_{\nu})'=T'^{\mu\nu}V'_{\nu}.$$ If $T$ is a tensor, this is clearly true. Is such a 'linearity' also true for a generic $T$? If not, is there an example where this is not true that does not involve derivatives?

Also, why does $\partial^{\mu}\nabla^{\nu}$ not falsify this statement? It is not a tensor, yet its contraction with $V_{\nu}$ is.

EDIT:
An example with less ambiguity is $\partial^{\mu}W^{\nu}V_{\nu}$ for some vector $W^{\mu}$. This is a vector, but we would then draw the false conclusion that $\partial^{\mu}W^{\nu}$ is a tensor.

Also to clarify, my question is not about how to prove this theorem. My question is about i) why the the equation I wrote out for co-ordinate transformation holds in general, given that we have no idea what kind of object $T$ is, and ii) why my example does not disprove the theorem.

EDIT2: Here is a proof that $\nabla_{\mu}V^{\mu}$ is a scalar, so that we can move past this and address my question. Either you use that we are contracting two vectors, and so it is clearly a scalar since the equation must have homogeneous weight. Or we can do it 'properly':
Let $$J^{\mu}_{\nu} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x'^{\nu}}.$$ Then $$\partial_{\sigma} \text{log}\det J = \partial_{\sigma}\text{Tr}\text{log}J = \text{Tr}\partial_{\sigma}\text{log}J =\text{Tr} J^{-1}\partial_{\sigma}J = 0$$ since $$\partial_{\sigma}J^{\mu}_{\nu} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^{\nu}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\sigma}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^{\nu}} \delta^{\mu}_{\sigma}= 0.$$ Similarly 
$$ \frac{\partial x^{\sigma}}{\partial x'^{\mu}}\partial_{\sigma}\frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}=0,$$
again just by the chain rule, commutativity of derivatives, and the fact that the Kronecker delta is constant. It is now trivial to see that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{g}V^{\mu}) &\rightarrow\frac{\partial x^{\sigma}}{\partial x'^{\mu}}\frac{1}{\text{det}J\sqrt{g}}\partial_{\sigma}(\text{det}J \sqrt{g}\frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}V^{\nu})\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{g}V^{\mu}).
\end{align*}

Comment: If you are in a context where $\partial$ and $\nabla$ are different, $\partial$ is not a vector

Comment: $\nabla^{\mu}V_{\mu}$ is a scalar so $\partial$ should be a vector in that case? @Gabriel Golfetti

Comment: $\partial^\mu(\nabla^\nu V_\nu)$ is not a vector unless the metric is constant, in which trivially $\partial=\nabla$ and $\partial^\mu\partial^\nu$ is a tensor.

Comment: The covariant derivative reduces to the partial derivative on a scalar though, so how is it not a vector? @Gabriel Golfetti

Comment: Where is the physics in this question?

Comment: Well this claim is in a book called General Relativity: and introduction for physicists, so I suppose it is related to physics.

Comment: I am not sure starting from second line of your derivation. Let $J=\partial\left(r\theta\phi\right)/\partial\left(xyz\right)=1/r^2\sin\theta$, i.e. $S$ is spherical coordinates and $S'$ is Carthesian. Then $\partial_\sigma \log J=\partial_\sigma \left(-2\log r - \log\sin\theta\right)=-\frac{2}{r}\delta^r_\sigma-\cot\theta \delta^\theta_\sigma\neq0$. This counter-example shows there is something wrong (maybe I missed something?)

Comment: Also note that you cannot swap partial derivatives from different coordinates like you do in Eq 4. Consider spherical and Cartsian coordinates $\partial_\theta \left(\partial_x \theta\right)=\partial_\theta \left(\cos\theta\cos\phi/r\right)=-\sin\theta\cos\phi/r$

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply write out how a vector transforms, how tensor transforms and do it by linear algebra.

Let $S:\{x^\alpha\}^{\alpha=1\dots N}$ be one set of coordinates and $\tilde{S}:\{x^\alpha\}^{\alpha=1\dots N}$ be another set.

If $V_\alpha$ is a co-vector in $S$ whilst $\tilde{V}_\alpha$ is a co-vector in $\tilde{S}$, then, by definition:

$V_\alpha = \frac{\partial \tilde{x}^\beta}{\partial x^\alpha}\tilde{V}_\beta$, 
and, inverting this 
$\tilde{V}_\mu = \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial \tilde{x}^\mu}V_\beta$

Similarly if $T^{\alpha\beta}V_\beta$ is a vector then:

$\left(T^{\alpha\beta}V_\beta\right)=\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial \tilde{x}^\gamma}\tilde{\left(T^{\gamma\mu}V_\mu\right)}=\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial \tilde{x}^\gamma}\left(\tilde{T}^{\gamma\mu}\tilde{V}_\mu\right)=\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial \tilde{x}^\gamma}\tilde{T}^{\gamma\mu}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial \tilde{x}^\mu}V_\beta$

If this is true for all $V_\alpha$ in co-vector space, your result should be easy to prove.

Regarding the $\nabla^\nu V_\nu$. Do it properly, assuming Levi-Civita connection:

$\nabla^\nu V_\nu = g^{\nu\mu}\nabla_\mu V_\nu=\nabla_\mu g^{\nu\mu} V_\nu=\nabla_\mu V^\mu = \partial_\mu V^\mu + \Gamma^\eta_{\mu\eta}V^\mu=\partial_\mu V^\mu + \frac{\partial_\mu g}{2g} V^\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_\mu\left(\sqrt{g} V^\mu\right)$

This is not necessarily a true scalar, because determinant of the metric is not a scalar (it is more like a density that picks up jacobian determinant when one changes coordinates). Hence partial derivative of this is not necessarily a vector/co-vector. See Rund & Lovelock.

---

Following comments. I repeat. Do it properly. Let's look at the weight.

$\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_\nu\left(\sqrt{g}V^\nu\right)$

in coordinates $S$. What would it be in $\tilde{S}$? Let's do it bit by bit. Firstly $g=J^2\cdot\tilde{g}$, where $J=\left|\frac{\partial\left(\tilde{x}\right)}{\partial\left(x\right)}\right|$

Then:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_\nu\left(\sqrt{g}V^\nu\right)=\frac{1}{J\cdot\sqrt{\tilde{g}}}\cdot\frac{\partial \tilde{x}^\kappa}{\partial x^\nu}\tilde{\partial}_\kappa \left(J\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial \tilde{x}^\alpha}\sqrt{\tilde{g}} \tilde{V}^\alpha\right) $

So:

$\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_\nu\left(\sqrt{g}V^\nu\right) = \frac{\tilde{\partial}_\alpha J}{J}\tilde{V}^\alpha + \left(\partial_\alpha V^\alpha -\tilde{\partial}_\alpha \tilde{V}^\alpha\right) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\tilde{g}}}\cdot\tilde{\partial}_\mu \left(\sqrt{\tilde{g}} \tilde{V}^\mu\right)\neq\tilde{\phi}$

Where one would expect:

$\tilde{\phi}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tilde{g}}}\cdot\tilde{\partial}_\mu \left(\sqrt{\tilde{g}} \tilde{V}^\mu\right)$

Unless you can make the first two terms disappear, I maintain that $\phi$ is not a true scalar.

Similar arguments go for the other bit. Show your work, then we could try to find the problem.

---

Yet another addition

Ok, lets back up. You have a co-vector $V_\mu$ and a vector $U^\nu=T^{\nu\mu}V_\mu$, where $T^{\mu\nu}$ is simply a linear transformation that works in coordinates $S$.

Question 1. Does this hold for *any* co-vector $V_\mu$, i.e. is $U^\nu=T^{\nu\mu}V_\mu$ a vector for all co-vectors?

Question 2. You then proceed to talk about $\tilde{T}^{\nu\mu}$ which is $T'^{\nu\mu}$ in your notation. What is that object?

You said '''the definition of $\tilde{T}$ is whatever $T$ looks like in the new co-ordinate system'''. This is too vague. There are clear rules for transforming tensors between different coordinate frames, but everything else needs additional work. Currently your main question is like this ''Lets say I have A and B. How do I proove that A=B, but without defining what is A?'' I got around this by incorporating definition into the derivation. You did not like this. So what is your definition of $\tilde{T}$

Comment: Thanks. I agree that the determinant of the metric is a tensor density. Does the last expression you wrote not have weight -1+1=0, and so it is a true scalar?

Comment: Also my first question is much more stupid than what you've been talking about. Why is $\tilde{(T^{\gamma\mu}V_{\mu})}=\tilde{T}^{\gamma\mu}\tilde{V}_{\mu}$ and not, say, $\tilde{T}^{\gamma\mu}\tilde{V}_{\mu} + K^{\gamma}$?

Comment: @gmarocco: I don't know about weight. You would need to check. Evaluate $\nabla^\nu V_\nu$ in two different coordinate systems and see if you get the same result. I don't think the weight will be trivial, because of the $\partial_\mu$

Comment: @gmarocco: Do you have a definition for $\tilde{T}^{\mu\nu}$? I guess not, because until you prove that $T^{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor, it should be treated as a symbol tied to a particular coordinte system. If I am correct, then $\tilde{\left(T^{\gamma\mu}V_\mu\right)}=\tilde{T^{\gamma\mu}}\tilde{V_\mu}$ defines $\tilde{T^{\gamma\mu}}$.

Comment: @gmarocco: The $+K^\gamma$ term could be ruled out based on the linearity of the LHS, and linearity of operation of changing coordinate basis

Comment: It is weight 0. You don't even need my example: consider $\partial^{\mu}W^{\nu}V_{\nu}$ for some vector $W$. This satisfies the conditions; $\partial^{\mu}W^{\nu}$ is not a tensor. @Cryo

Comment: Also the LHS is only linear if the object is a tensor (which is a linear map). A more general object need not commute in this sense with co-ordinate transformations (at least not as far as I can tell). I am happy to see a proof of this for a generic object $T$ - that is basically what I am asking for.

Comment: Also you cannot take the expression you wrote as the definition of $\tilde{T}$: the definition of $\tilde{T}$ is whatever $T$ looks like in the new co-ordinate system, which need not be the same as the object your wrote down and are calling $\tilde{T}$.

Comment: @gmarocco: Put your arguments in a proper derivation. Otherwise, there is nothing I can do. See above for example

Comment: please see my edit. @Cryo

Comment: and now please see my edits :-) @gmarocco

Comment: I think your last point is basically coming to the heart of the question. I have a covector $V_{\mu}$, I have a vector $W^{\mu} = T^{\mu\nu}V_{\nu}$. Let's assume W is a vector for all covectors V. All I know about T is that it is some object with two indices, and satisfies the conditions mentioned. I know nothing else. If I assume that $T$ is a linear transformation as you said, then this all problem is tautological. $T'$, by definition, is the representation of $T$ is my new co-ordinate system. If this is too vague to make any statements about $T/T'$, then we agree that the theorem is false.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$V=V_{\mu} dx^{\mu}$$ be the co-vector, and let

$$T=T^{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}$$

be the tensor.

And let the tensor product of $T$ and $V$ be

$$T^{'}=T^{\mu\nu}V_{\nu} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\otimes dx^{\nu}$$.

Contraction (see "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction") is summing over $2$ like indices, which in your case, you would leave you with a vector

$$T^{'}=T^{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}$$

after contraction - which may appear to work at a singe point on the manifold.

But you still haven't proved $T=T^{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}$ is a tensor.

There's only $1$ way to show that $T$ is tensor, and that's to show it transforms like a tensor under a change of coordinates.

Comment: "There's only 1 way to show that T is tensor" not true. Another way is to for example check wheter we are dealing with multilinear map $V\times V\times...\times V^*\times V^*\times...\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $V$ being som vector space

Answer (score -2):

A tensor is just a multi linear function. So you just check for linearity that's it.

Edit: this is quite trivial.
 If after contraction it is  linear in all arguments and contraction is linear its a tensor.

Comment: This is incorrect. You also have to show that the tensor transforms appropriately under changes of coordinates. Otherwise the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}$, the derivatives $\partial_\mu$, the Levi-Civita tensor $\epsilon_{\mu_1\ldots\mu_d}$ would all be tensors.

Comment: Yes it does....

Comment: In the context of GR "a tensor" usually means "a tensor *field*" on the spacetime manifold $\mathcal{M}$. The question is about whether some function that gives a matrix from the coordinates defines a tensor field, i.e. has the "right transformation properties", not whether something is a tensor at a specific point.

Comment: This doesn't matter. A tensor is a tensor. How it transforms is not relevant. A tensor on the spacetime manifold M is just a multi linear function on the vector fields on that manifold.

Comment: @MannyC transformation rule is directly derivable from multilinearity of the function plus transformation properties of the arguments. So no, you do not need to show transformation properties, if you showed multilinearity.

Comment: @Umaxo To reiterate $\Gamma: (V,U,W)\mapsto U^\mu W^\nu V_\rho \Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}$ is multilinear and yet not a tensor. At least not in the usual sense used in GR. If you have a different notion of tensor in this context, that's just terminology.

Comment: @MannyC The map you wrote is misinterpretation of Christofell symbols though. The definition of them is $\Gamma^k_{ij}=e^k(\nabla_i e_j)$ The map is $\Gamma(V,U,W)\rightarrow V(\nabla_U W)=V_kU_i e^k(\nabla_i (W^je_j))=V_kU_iW^j e^k(\nabla_i (e_j))+V_kU_i e^k(e_j)(\nabla_i W^j)$ which because of the second term is not multilinear. If the map would be defined the way you do it, then it is multilinear, but it would not have meaning of Christoffel symbols